# Shrinking list width to visible list items with animations

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a "slots animation effect" by animating list items in and out of view.  However, the list width remains the size of its widest item, regardless of if it is visible.  I would like to focus on the initial and last values displayed - and corresponding widths before and after the animation has completed.

How can I achieve the desired result (changing the width of the ul) depending on what is in view?  I hope to minimize the required JavaScript, but can accept it as needed.

My example code is at https://codepen.io/ItGumby/pen/MWgKXLx

html:

```js
let c = document.querySelector('.slots ul').childElementCount;
document.querySelector('.slots').style.setProperty('--count', c - 1);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hide scrollbars */
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: #eee;
}
body h2 {
  color: lightgreen;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  /* todo: adjust width of parent to fit */
}

.slots {
  /* https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20properties
  don't work in IE11; would need to render from hippo */
  --size: 3rem;
  --count: 3;
  /* 1 less than real count */
  display: flex;
  /* inline the paragraphs, list */
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: var(--size);
  line-height: calc(1.2 * var(--size));
  height: calc(1.2 * var(--size));
}
.slots p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.slots ul {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slots;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes slots {
  from {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  45% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  60% {
    margin-top: calc(-1.35 * var(--size) * var(--count));
  }
  61% {
    margin-top: calc(-1.2 * var(--size) * var(--count));
  }
  to {
    margin-top: calc(-1.2 * var(--size) * var(--count));
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Slots:
</h2>
<div class="slots">
  <p>
    hello
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      one
    </li>
    <li>
      two
    </li>
    <li>
      three long words
    </li>
    <li>
      short
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    world
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the width is staying the same on your LI items is because they're still being displayed inside of the UL, which dictates the width. If you set the ones outside of the desired view port (the slot you want visible) to 'display:none', then the problem solves itself.